# Create clusters on images using KMeans clustering

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning

I have around 50000 images belonging to 9 different classes. (shirt, tshirt, pant etc)

I am creating a program that will classify new images into one of the classes with a good accuracy. While this is a standard classification problem, the accuracy is not good as some of the classes do not differ by a lot. example a denim jeans looks similar to a formal pant except probably the color and texture.

I was hoping I could use unsupervised learning to tackle this problem.
But i am getting this error message while passing images to the K Means method

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

this is my code overall

```
data_path = '../DATASET/category/train/'
ls = []
dic = {}

for classes in sorted(os.listdir(data_path)):
    if classes.startswith('.'): continue
    for image in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(data_path,classes))):
        if image.startswith('.'): continue
        img = np.array(plt.imread(os.path.join(data_path,classes,image)))
        ls.append((classes, img))

cls = [i[0] for i in ls]
img = [i[1] for i in ls]

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['img'] = img
df['label'] = cls

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=9) 
kmeans.fit(X)
```

What am i doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to extract features from each image and then plug it to KMeans. Please see the example here: https://www.kaggle.com/shinto/k-means-clustering